# AIX update environment after .profile change

Tags: unix, shell, aix, profile, sh

I am running AIX 5.3.  I have made changes to a user's .profile file (added a couple of environment variables).

Is there a command that I can use to re-process the .profile file for a particular user without them having to log out and then back in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the user's shell prompt:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Or

```
. ~/.profile
```

Comment: I do not have to do this often.  I appreciate the quick response!